# Azure queues read / write limitations

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, azure, cloud

is there a way to let one side WRITE ONLY to a queue and the other side to READ from the queue in azure? (something like private public key thinking...)

is there a way to do so with queue service bus?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with both; however, the Service Bus Queues make it easier with ACS.

For the Storage Queues you need to create a Shared Access Signature to do this.  You can find out more about that from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx).

Note that with the Storage Queue approach using SAS you need a service or manual process to create and provide the SAS url prior to hitting the queue or for when the SAS expires.  That SAS can last a while (just like the token from ACS can); however, with the ACS approach you don't need your own service out there creating SAS urls for clients.